# Conditional Logic on Pandas Dataframe Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I am fairly new to Python, so forgive the possibly trivial question.

I am trying to generate Buy and Sell signals given a change in the `RSI` value I have calculated for a specific futures contract. In my `DataFrame`, I have created a column called R`S`I which contains the values I am referencing, and what I would like to do is check each proceeding value according to a predetermined logic, and if that criteria is met , Generate "Buy" or "Sell", then increment a count for each signal generated.  i.e. I imagine a solution that compares `[i]` and `[i+1]` using a `for` loop , but I get an error that reads -

```
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on class'pandas.indexes.range.RangeIndex with these indexers [25.714285714285722] of class 'numpy.float64'
```

This is my code

```
for i in es.RSI:
    Buy = 0
    Sell = 0
    if es.RSI[i] < 30.0 and es.RSI[i+1] >30.0:
        es.RSI[i] = "Buy"
        Buy = Buy +1

    if es.RSI[i] >70.0 and es.RSI[i+1] < 70.0 :
        es.RSI[i] = "Sell"
        Sell = Sell +1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it looks like you're using a float for an array index value. Perhaps try replacing each index of

```
es.RSI[i]
```

with

```
es.RSI[int(i)]
```

(Same thing with es.RSI[i+1], replace it with es.RSI[int(i)+1].)

Comment: Thank you,  My code runs now with no errors.  Curious as to why I would need to specify that [i] as an integer.  I would think that an indexer would default as an integer no?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop

```
for i in es.RSI:
```

iterate over items from `er.RSI` array, so your `i` contains value of RSI, not index of array. That's why you see this error

```
TypeError: cannot do label indexing on class'pandas.indexes.range.RangeIndex with these indexers [25.714285714285722] of class 'numpy.float64'
```

To iterate over array index you should use

```
for i in range(len(es.RSI)-1):
```